# Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to required type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owner/terminals/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveTerminal( @RequestParam(value = "name") String name, 
                            @RequestParam(value = "file") @Valid OnlyForImagesFileWrapper file,
                               BindingResult bindingResult )
             {
                ...
```

and I see the following stacktrace:

```
    org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to required type 'com.terminal.domain.validation.OnlyForImagesFileWrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [com.terminal.domain.validation.OnlyForImagesFileWrapper]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at           org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:74)
        ....
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [com.terminal.domain.validation.OnlyForImagesFileWrapper]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
            at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
            ... 71 more
```

OnlyForImagesFileWrapper source:

```
public class OnlyForImagesFileWrapper {
    @Extensions(imageFormats = {".jpg",".png",".gif",".bmp"}, videoFormats = {})
    private MultipartFile multipartFile;
    ...
}
```

How to avoid the problem?

Where can I set conversion politic for this controller method for multipart file?

**P.S.**

I tryed to write my custom initbinder:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(CommonsMultipartFile.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setValue(Object file) {
                setValue(new OnlyForImagesFileWrapper((MultipartFile) file));
            }
        });
    }
```

But this method doesn't invoke when I submit form and I see stacktrace mentioned above.

**P.S.**

result after **M. Deinum** instruction execution(when I inside `saveTerminal` method):

[image: http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/150502/e592df25e4.jpg]

Also I noticed that my initbinder method doesn't invoke.

More details about my code(state after M. Denium advice):

jsp:

```
<input type="file" id="newFile" name="file" class="file" size="21.5" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif,.bmp" style="opacity: 0;">
```

arguments of controller method:

```
...
@ModelAttribute @Valid OnlyForImagesFileWrapper wrapper,
                               BindingResult bindingResult,
...
```

Comment: Have you read the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)... Also if you want binding then use binding. Add a property `name` of type `String` and rename `multipartFile` to `file`. Remote the `@RequestParam`s from the method and just annotate the method argument typed `OnlyForImagesFileWrapper` with `@ModelAttribute`. You are mixing and confusing a lot of things and with that make things a lot complexer then needed.

Comment: @M. Deinum in reference quid written how can I accept MultipartFile as method attribute. In my case I want to accept wrapper over the MultipartFile

Comment: @M. Deinum **Add a property name of type String and rename multipartFile to file** where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented you are making things too complex. Change your wrapper to the following (with the appropriate getters and setters).

```
public class OnlyForImagesFileWrapper {
    @Extensions(imageFormats = {".jpg",".png",".gif",".bmp"}, videoFormats = {})
    private MultipartFile file;
    private String name;
...
}
```

Then your controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owner/terminals/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveTerminal( @ModelAttribute @Valid OnlyForImagesFileWrapper wrapper, BindingResult bindingResult ) { ... }
```

And of course in your configuration make sure you have a `MultipartFileResolver` configured to properly handle the `MultipartFile` argument as explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart).

Comment: After execution your instructions saveTerminal always accepts null argument http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/150502/e592df25e4.jpg

Comment: You haven't done what I told you to do. You haven't renamed your attribute from `multipartFile` to `file`. Also you should remove your init binder method as it doesn't do a thing.

Comment: can you explain why I should rename multipartFile to file ?  file is name of what?

Comment: looks like it is name from jsp

Comment: Request parameters are bound to properties of the same name. So if you have a request parameter `file` you should have a `setFile` method on your model object. (How the internal field is called doesn't really matter the name of the getter/setter defines the name of the property).